# How do you pass variables into widget_html

Tags: r, htmlwidgets

**Question**

The last section of the htmlwidgets.org page on [*Custom widget HTML*](http://www.htmlwidgets.org/develop_advanced.html) says you can add your own html to a widget by creating a function called `<widget_name>_html`

How do you pass variables in to this function?

**Example**

I have created a new package called *myWidgetHTML*, and run `htmlwidgets::scaffoldWidget(name = "myHTML”)`. The package is hosted on my [github page](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/myWidgetHTML/commit/2c778fe26839f219fa346c6fd44229ab868fd325)

Within the generated `R/myHTML.R` file, I have created the function

```
#' @import htmltools
myHTML_html <- function(id, class, style, ...){
    myString <- "hello world"
    tags$p(myString)
}
```

building and running the widget generates the string `hello world` as expected

```
library(myWidgetHTML)
myHTML(message = "")
```

[image]

What I can't figure out is how to write the function so that I can pass the variable `myString`into it:

```
#' @import htmltools
#' @export
myHTML_html <- function(id, class, style, myString, ...){
    tags$p(myString)
}
```

Going through the [source code for the widgets](https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets/blob/master/R/htmlwidgets.R) hasn't shed any light as the relevant section (copied below) suggests it accepts further arguments through `...`, but I can't see where to send them in from.

```
widget_html <- function(name, package, id, style, class, inline = FALSE, ...){

  # attempt to lookup custom html function for widget
  fn <- tryCatch(get(paste0(name, "_html"),
                     asNamespace(package),
                     inherits = FALSE),
                 error = function(e) NULL)

  # call the custom function if we have one, otherwise create a div
  if (is.function(fn)) {
    fn(id = id, style = style, class = class, ...)
  } else if (inline) {
    tags$span(id = id, style = style, class = class)
  } else {
    tags$div(id = id, style = style, class = class)
  }
}
```

Comment: I've been [informed by one of the contributors](https://twitter.com/timelyportfolio/status/752313318610644992) to `htmlwidgets` that this isn't possible at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To close off this question, the official answer is that this is not possible.

Reference: 
[This tweet](https://twitter.com/timelyportfolio/status/752313318610644992) from @timelyportfolio

> as of now, no real way to accomplish this

I thought a possible solution would be to pass `x` into `widget_html`, and so proposed this as a potential solution. However, @jjallaire points out this won't work when used with Shiny

Reference: 
[Issue 212](https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets/issues/212)

> The problem is that within Shiny applications "x" is not yet known at the time widget_html is called. The best way to accomplish this is to mutate the DOM as needed within the first call to renderValue on the JavaScript side.